# Scaling and size-reducing image on a server

Tags: java, image-processing, headless

I need to scale down an JPG image so that it fits in a 1024x640 rectangle and save it so that it's size is no more than 20 kB. With some googling, I managed to do both. For the scaling I use

```
private static BufferedImage scale(BufferedImage input, int width, int height) {
    final int type = input.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
    final BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
    final Graphics2D g2 = result.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(input, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g2.dispose();
    return result;
}
```

and for the size-reduction, I use `ImageWriter` with `JPEGImageWriteParam` and repeat with decreased quality until the file size gets below the limit.

It both works rather nicely on my machine, but on the test server, it does terrible things:

```
original file size:    174548
scaled down file size:  16995 - on my machine
                       228218 - on the server
```

So the scaled-down image is bigger than the original and the quality is awful.

I though it could be related to the [headless java problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4534680/581205), but the java installation is not headless (and I never get an `HeadlessException`):

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: The problem could be a large amount of meta data. I do not know Java, but in command line you can use -strip to remove most if not all meta data. Also in command line, there is a define that allows Imagemagick to output your desired file size. See -define jpeg:extent={size} at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg_write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the resizing done using `Graphics2D`. Not idea why it did what it did, but after replacing it with [java-image-scaling](https://github.com/mortennobel/java-image-scaling), the problem is gone.

It's quite possible that there are better libraries out there, but for current needs this one works good enough.

Comment: java-image-scaling is dead since 2014. I made a replacement at https://github.com/MarkJeronimus/ImageUtilities

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Thanks, I'll look into it if I'll need to rework it. For now, it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

We used **ImageMagick** for image resizing and re-formatting. It can give you flexibility. We managed to use it earlier for similar need to as of yours.

*ImageMagick utilizes multiple computational threads to increase performance and can read, process, or write mega-, giga-, or tera-pixel image sizes.*

It is free an open-source. You can refer official website for more detils : https://imagemagick.org/index.php

Sample program works like as below:

```
ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();

// create the operation, add images and operators/options
IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
op.addImage("source_picture.jpg"); // source file
op.resize(800,600);
// of op.resize(800); // and height calculate automatically
op.addImage("resized_picture.jpg"); // destination file file

// execute the operation
cmd.run(op);
```

Check related stackoverflow thread [Image magick java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150503/image-magick-java)

Hope it helps!